# What do .pmdlg files mean when building simscape code libraries in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

When building simscape custom code libraries matlab generates files into the sscprj folder and generates files with extensions md5, mexw64 and pmdlg for each custom code component. The mexw64 is a mex file and the md5 is for file integrity checking. Does anyone know what the pmdlg file is for?

Is it something to do with the mask dialog of the component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but being an internal file format, there's no way of knowing for sure. My guess is that `pm` stands for physical modelling and `dlg` for dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I ran a little experiment to check and it looks like the pmdlg file contains the dialog box that opens when you double click on a component. In the absence of the file I get an error message when trying to double click on a component saying that it doesn't know how to open the dialog. When the pmdlg file is there the dialog box does open. I think that confirms it.